# Adding a comment inside Piecewise affects box parsing

Tags: bugs, piecewise

Adding a comment in `Piecewise` affects how underlying box structure is being parsed (see the screenshot).

I use Mathematica 11.3 on Linux.

[image]

Comment: It appears to be the problem with the front-end parsing underlying box structure. Try this instead `Piecewise[{{1 (**), x}, {0, True}}]`. I can confirm that the problem is present at MMA 11.2 @ Win10.

Comment: With v11.3 on a Mac both `Piecewise[{{1(**), x}, {0, True}}]` and `Piecewise[{{1 (**), x}, {0, True}}]` produce the expected output.

Comment: @BobHanlon If you type them in the form as you did, it will work because you are typing in `FullForm` and the expression is not processed by the front-end. However, if you type in the form as posted in the question, using `\[Piecewise]` followd by CTRL-ENTER to create matrix form, it fails.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment, to me it looks like a problem with the front-end parsing.